# Vim substitute() function flags order changes its behavior?

Tags: vim

I have the following line made of tab separated strings ; I have sometimes multiple sequential `<Tab>`:

```
zer<Tab><Tab>abc<Tab>def<Tab><Tab>iop<Tab><Tab>
```

I want to insert the 'null' string between 2 consecutive `<Tab>` ; I run the following command:

```
:s/\t\(\t\)\@=/\tnull/eg
```

which give me as I expected:

```
zer<Tab>null<Tab>abc<Tab>def<Tab>null<Tab>iop<Tab>null<Tab>
```

The equivalent substitute function to the above command is (I echoed its result):

```
:echo substitute(getline('.'),'\t\(\t\)\@=','\tnull','eg')
```

which insert a `<Tab>` only  between the first two `<Tab>`s:

```
zer<Tab>null<Tab>abc<Tab>def<Tab><Tab>iop<Tab><Tab>
```

whereas if I  **change the order of the substitute flags** in the substitute function call  (**`'eg'`** replaced by **`'ge'`**):

```
    :echo substitute(getline('.'),'\t\(\t\)\@=','\tnull','ge')
```

Then I get the expected result:

```
zer<Tab>null<Tab>abc<Tab>def<Tab>null<Tab>iop<Tab>null<Tab>
```

It seems that the order of the flags in the substitute() function change its behavior while it has no effect for the substitute command.
Does anyone have an idea why that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `:substitute` *command* can take many flags, but the `substitute()` *function* only supports the `g` flag. Flags like `c` (for interactivity) or `e` (for error suppression) do not apply to the low-level function.

Answer (score 1):

From my limited understanding of C, it [looks](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/137374fd6538cf9dee0cb22907728d8fdecb5832/src/eval.c#L10154) like Vim only cares about the `{flags}` argument if its first character is `g`:

```
do_all = (flags[0] == 'g');
[…]
if (!do_all)
    break;
```

This may explain the fact that `:help substitute()` only mentions `g` when explaining `{flags}`:

```
When {flags} is "g", all matches of {pat} in {expr} are
replaced.  Otherwise {flags} should be "".
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment ; I still cannot explain why the `substitute()` fonction behavior differs from the `:s` command while used with the same flags order.

Comment: For that you will have to ask on the vim_dev mailing list.